# Oracle SQL order by case condition

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I have problem how to write sql statement with ORDER BY and CASE over parameter

Input parameter:

p_desc = 0 
p_sort_by = 'name'

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE NVL(p_desc, 0) WHEN 1 THEN NVL(p_sort_by, 1) END DESC,
  CASE NVL(p_desc, 0) WHEN 0 THEN NVL(p_sort_by, 1) END ASC
```

Comment: Presumably you are trying to sort by the column whose name is provided by `p_name`, not by the literal value of that string, which would be pointless... but you can't use a parameter to represent a table or column name. How many possible values can there be? You probably just want to test for each known value.

Comment: Yes, I want to sort by column name with name ```p_name```. There can be 12 possible values until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White-list all the combinations using `CASE` expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause. When the condition is not matched then the `CASE` expression will return `NULL` and all rows will have the same ordering for that un-matched `CASE` expression so only the matched `CASE` expression will have any effect on the ordering.

```sql
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN p_sort_by = 'COLUMN1' AND NVL(p_desc, 0) = 0 THEN column1 END ASC,
  CASE WHEN p_sort_by = 'COLUMN1' AND p_desc = 1         THEN column1 END DESC,
  CASE WHEN p_sort_by = 'COLUMN2' AND NVL(p_desc, 0) = 0 THEN column2 END ASC,
  CASE WHEN p_sort_by = 'COLUMN2' AND p_desc = 1         THEN column2 END DESC,
  CASE WHEN p_sort_by = 'COLUMN3' AND NVL(p_desc, 0) = 0 THEN column3 END ASC,
  CASE WHEN p_sort_by = 'COLUMN3' AND p_desc = 1         THEN column3 END DESC,
  CASE WHEN p_sort_by = 'COLUMN4' AND NVL(p_desc, 0) = 0 THEN column4 END ASC,
  CASE WHEN p_sort_by = 'COLUMN4' AND p_desc = 1         THEN column4 END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be *dynamic*, perhaps a function that returns ref cursor could help. Here's example.

Function composes `SELECT` statement and replaces parameters' *placeholders* with values you pass to the function.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test(p_desc in number, p_sort_by in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(500);
  5    rc    sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    l_str := 'select empno, ename, job, sal from emp where deptno = 10 ' ||
  8             'order by ' ||
  9             'case nvl(p_desc, 0) when 1 then nvl(p_sort_by, 1) end desc, ' ||
 10             'case nvl(p_desc, 0) when 0 then nvl(p_sort_by, 1) end asc';
 11
 12    l_str := replace(l_str, 'p_desc', p_desc);
 13    l_str := replace(l_str, 'p_sort_by', p_sort_by);
 14
 15    open rc for l_str;
 16    return rc;
 17  end;
 18  /

Function created.
```

Let's try it: sort result by `ename` in ascending order:

```
SQL> select f_test(0, 'ename') from dual;

F_TEST(0,'ENAME')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
```

Sort by `ename` in descending order:

```
SQL> select f_test(1, 'ename') from dual;

F_TEST(1,'ENAME')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
```

Sort by `job` in ascending order:

```
SQL> select f_test(0, 'job') from dual;

F_TEST(0,'JOB')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
```